# Program crashes when exe is copied to different computer

Tags: deployment, windows-7, .net-4.0, reference, sharpdevelop

I have written a program in c# on my Windows 7 computer with .NET 4.0 using Sharp Develop 4.2.
I then changed it to a release within Sharp Develop, built it, and copied the .exe in the bin\Release folder to another Windows 7 computer with .NET 4.0.  It crashes immediately without loading the initial form and gives no specific error.  My MainForm method is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace BiasTracker1._
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
//Here are my initial variables

public static SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
public static DataSet ds = new DataSet();
public static DataTable DisplayTable = ds.Tables.Add("DisplayTable");
SqlDataAdapter RawDataDA;
SqlCommandBuilder RawSampleSCB;
public static DataTable InstrumentDetail = ds.Tables.Add("InstrumentDetail");
public static string DatabaseOwner;
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart CurrentChart;
public static DataTable ImportDataTable = new DataTable();
public static string NewTransfer;
public static bool ValidatePerCell = true;
public static Image chart1Image;
public static string Title;
public static string NIRLabString;
bool ChangesNotDisplayed = false;
Point PreviousChartLocation;
List<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint> SelectedPoints = new List<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint>();
List<DataRow> SelectedRows = new List<DataRow>();
static double EPS = 2.22045e-016;
double FPMIN = 2.22507e-308 / EPS;
public static CustomPrintDoc pd = new CustomPrintDoc();
int NumOfParametersInReport = 0;
public static SqlConnectionStringBuilder SimPlusConn;
public static string SimPlusProductGUID;
public static string SimPlusSiteCode;
public double[] cof = new double[] {-1.3026537197817904,0.64196979235649026,0.019476473204185836,-0.009561514786808631,-0.000946595344482036,0.000366839497852761,0.000042523324806907,-0.000020278578112534,-0.000001624290004647,0.00000130365583558,0.000000015626441722,-0.000000085238095915,0.000000006529054439,0.000000005059343495,-0.000000000991364156,-0.000000000227365122,0.000000000096467911,0.000000000002394038,-0.000000000006886027,0.000000000000894487,0.000000000000313092,-0.000000000000112708,0.000000000000000381,0.000000000000007106,-0.000000000000001523,-0.000000000000000094,0.000000000000000121,-0.000000000000000028};
Point? prevPosition = null;
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();

public MainForm()
{
     try
     {
          InitializeComponent();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Failed in Initialization.\n" + ex.ToString());
     }
     //Test SQL Connection
     FileStream ConnectionStream;
     try
     {
          ConnectionStream = new FileStream(@"C:\BiasTracker\settings.ini",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
     }
     catch(DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Not able to find ini... Creating one.");
          Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\BiasTracker");
          ConnectionStream = new FileStream(@"C:\BiasTracker\settings.ini",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
     }
     try
     {
          StreamReader ConnectionRdr = new StreamReader(ConnectionStream);
          string line = null;
          if((line = ConnectionRdr.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
               sqlBldr.DataSource = line;
               sqlBldr.Password = ConnectionRdr.ReadLine();
               sqlBldr.UserID = ConnectionRdr.ReadLine();
               sqlBldr.InitialCatalog = ConnectionRdr.ReadLine();
          }
          else
          {
               sqlBldr.DataSource = ".\\SQLEXPRESS";
               sqlBldr.Password = "password";
               sqlBldr.UserID = "sa";
               sqlBldr.InitialCatalog = "BiasMaster";
               StreamWriter ConnectionWtr = new StreamWriter(ConnectionStream);
               ConnectionWtr.WriteLine(".\\SQLEXPRESS");
               ConnectionWtr.WriteLine("password");
               ConnectionWtr.WriteLine("sa");
               ConnectionWtr.WriteLine("BiasMaster");
               ConnectionWtr.WriteLine("applications\\SQLEXPRESS");
               ConnectionWtr.WriteLine("password");
               ConnectionWtr.WriteLine("sa");
               ConnectionWtr.WriteLine("BiasMaster");
               ConnectionWtr.Dispose();
          }
          ConnectionStream.Close();
          ConnectionStream.Dispose();
          ConnectionRdr.Dispose();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Not Able to read connection string\n" + ex.ToString());
     }
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection tmpConn;
     tmpConn = new SqlConnection(sqlBldr.ConnectionString);
     try                   //Test the connection and existence of the database
     {
          tmpConn.Open();
          tmpConn.Close();
     }
     catch
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Database Connection not Found.");
          tmpConn.Close();
     }

     SqlDataAdapter SettingsDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE SettingDesc = 'Owner'",sqlBldr.ConnectionString);
     DataTable SettingsTable = new DataTable();
     SettingsDA.Fill(SettingsTable);
     DatabaseOwner = SettingsTable.Rows[0][1].ToString();

     MakeTreeView();

}
```

MakeTreeView is surrounded by a try catch with a messagebox.

My Form loads these controls:

```
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemsimPlusImportToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabeltoolStripStatusLabel1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemsyncWithSharedServerToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemsyncToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemsetDBConnectionToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemtestToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemdetectOutliersToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemsaveToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemexcludeSelectedToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemgraphActionsToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxcomboBox7;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemprintReportToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemaddToReportToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chartchart4;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chartchart3;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Panelpanel2;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chartchart2;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxcomboBox6;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Labellabel7;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Buttonbutton3;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chartchart1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Buttonbutton2;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemremoveProductFormInstrumentToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemcopyInstrumentProductListToAnotherInstrumentToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemaddProductToInstrumentToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemaddParameterToProductToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemtablesToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemtXTToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemcSVToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItembiasDataToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemimportToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Labellabel1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxcomboBox1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Labellabel2;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxcomboBox2;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Labellabel3;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxcomboBox3;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Labellabel4;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxcomboBox4;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Labellabel5;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxcomboBox5;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Labellabel6;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerdateTimePicker1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerdateTimePicker2;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemparameterToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemproductToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuIteminstrumentToolStripMenuItem1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemlocationToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemcompanyToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemnewToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItemfileToolStripMenuItem;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.MenuStripmenuStrip1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.StatusStripstatusStrip1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.TabPagetabPage2;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewdataGridView1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.TreeViewtreeView1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Buttonbutton1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.Panelpanel1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.TabPagetabPage1;
privateSystem.Windows.Forms.TabControltabControl1;
```

The only thing I can think is that I am using a reference to something that the other computer does not have access to.  I thought it was the chart controls, but .NET 4.0 has those included.  Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: "No specific error"? Does it give any error at all?

Comment: I am a little new to Windows 7, but I think it is the equivalent of the send error report screen in xp.  I followed every bit of info it gave me, but could not seem to find any specifics. Just the name of my program.  If you know where to look, I may be able to give more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit.  It was the line:

```
DatabaseOwner = SettingsTable.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

I found it using AppDomain.UnhandledException.  It was a great tool if anyone else is running into a similar issue.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx